# How do I Merge Multiple CSV Files grouped by certain initial strings of the filename without headers(Except 1st) using a windows batch file

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

So we have many CSV files which come from different salesmen at different times throughout the Day,

Each of these CSVs contain certain information with 1st Line as a header line,
a single Salesmen can send multiple CSVs which may have multiple entries(lines),

the CSVs which Belong to the same Salesman are differentatied by the Time Stamps which are followed by the Name of the Salesman in the CSV Filename

Eg.

```
ABC_XYZ_SMAN_05092019_1232.csv

ABC_XYZ_SMAN_05092019_1148.csv

ABC_XYZ_SMAN_05092019_1556.csv
```

Above Entries Belong to the Salesman ABC_XYZ

In the Same Directory there are other Salesman's CSVs also

Eg.

```
QWE_RTY_SMAN_05092019_1323.csv

QWE_RTY_SMAN_05092019_0845.csv

QWE_RTY_SMAN_05092019_2238.csv
```

Above Entries Belong to the Salesman QWE_RTY

Each of these files have Information With 1st line as Headers.

My Goal is to create merged CSV for each salesman with only a single header and delete all the CSVs which create the Merged CSVs.

So

```
ABC_XYZ_SMAN_05092019.csv 

QWE_RTY_SMAN_05092019.csv
```

Would be the Output for the above Mentioned CSVs whith all the information and only one header on the 1st line.

all of this By using a Batch File.

Comment: Let us know how you got on, if the off topic code request hasn't been closed by then.

Comment: Batch files are not a good choice for this problem. It's like trying to change a tire with a hammer. Maybe with enough effort you could do it, but the results won't be pretty, and you would be much better off with a different tool.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Excuse me, but I disagree... Yes, Batch files are not the right tool in many cases, but in this particular problem I am sure that the 8-10 lines Batch file solution would be simpler than using any other tool...

Comment: @Aacini: I took that as a challenge... @Raymond: nine lines (readable code, without "code-golfing"). As a single line (not recommended - just for the challenge): `for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /on *_sman_*') do if exist "%%a_%%b_merged.csv" (more +1 "%%a_%%b_%%c" >>"%%a_%%b_merged.csv" & del "%%a_%%b_%%c") else (type "%%a_%%b_%%c" >"%%a_%%b_merged.csv" & del "%%a_%%b_%%c")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the salesman as Token1 and Token2 and the rest of the filename as Token3.
Check, if a summary exists. If yes, copy only the data (without header), if no, copy the whole file (including header).
Then delete the file.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b /on *_sman_*') do (
  if exist "%%a_%%b_merged.csv" (
    more +1 "%%a_%%b_%%c" >>"%%a_%%b_merged.csv"
  ) else (
    type "%%a_%%b_%%c" >"%%a_%%b_merged.csv"
  )
  del "%%a_%%b_%%c"
)
```

Note: the `more +1` trick only works with a limited number of lines (IIRC about 64.000). If you hit that limit, make sure, the salesman gets a rise.